# How to extract ASA 916.bin for using in GNS3?

Tags: linux, emulation, firewall, cisco

I have asa916.bin file. So I need to extract it into initrd and kernel files. Could anyone help to do this or give a reference of guide?
I doesn’t really matter the version of ASA. I just want to know a universal way how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

With arrival of Virtual ASA Images, there isn't much demand to hack ASA images and make them work with GNS3. Better option is to use ASAv Image in GNS3 for learning if you have access to one. If not, then VIRL is your next best option.